# AWS Lambda event filtering with the Java CDK

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

The event filter (DynamoDB in my case) appear very natural for the samples in JS but I've so far been unable to find any samples for the Java CDK. Something like

```
FilterCriteria.filter(Map.of("eventName", FilterRule.notEquals("DELETE")))
```

appear easy enough but how would you handle deeper nesting, e.g. a criteria for dynamodb.Keys.PK? Escape hatching into L1 and some pattern like in the JS samples?

Thanks in advance,
Nik

Comment: So what is the exact question here? Can you detail what JS samples you're referring to and which one you would like written using the Java CDK?

Comment: e.g in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial2.html there is code like
`- Pattern: '{"dynamodb": {"Keys": {"PK": { "S": [{ "prefix": "COMPANY" }] },"SK": { "S": [{ "prefix": "PRODUCT" }] }}}}'`
which nicely drills into the event